# How to pass Ansible variables to JMESPath query?

Tags: ansible, jmespath

Given the following playbook:

```
---
- name: "foo bar"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    foo:
     -
       a: aa
       b: bb
     -
       a: cc
       b: dd

  tasks:
   - debug:
       msg: " filter {{foo}} to  {{ foo | json_query(query)}} "

     vars:
       bar:  ['dd','ee']
       query: "[?a == 'cc' && contains (['dd','ee'],b)]"
       #query: "[?a == 'cc' && contains ( {{bar}} ,b)]"
```

I would like to pass a variable defined in ansible `bar:  ['dd','ee']` to a jmes_path query like `"[?a == 'cc' && contains ( {{bar}} ,b)]"`. Unfortunately, this does not work, the script fails.

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field
>   'args' has an invalid value ([]), and could not be converted to an
>   dict. Error was: Expecting: comma, got: literal: Parse error at column
>   28, token \"dd\" (LITERAL), for expression:\n\"[?a == 'cc' && contains
>   ( [u'dd', u'ee'] ,b)]\"\n                             ^\n\nThe error
>   appears to have been in
>   '/home/vagrant/testnew/lieferschein-deployment/stack.yml': line 16,
>   column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n   -
>   debug:\n     ^ here\n"}

However, defining the list in the query itself, inline like `"[?a == 'cc' && contains (['dd','ee'],b)]"`, it works without problems

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": " filter [{u'a': u'aa', u'b': u'bb'}, {u'a': u'cc', u'b': u'dd'}] to  [{u'a': u'cc', u'b': u'dd'}] "
}
```

**Is it possible to put an Ansible variable into the query, and if so, how?**

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
bar:  ['dd','ee']
```

to:

```
bar: "['dd','ee']"
```

Otherwise it is defined as an object, but you want a string.

---

If you already have a list defined, you need to stoop to checking [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html), find a proper filter and modify it to suit your needs:

> To concatenate a list into a string:
>
> ```
> {{ list | join(" ") }}
> ```

Comment: this works, but in a real playbook I would like to use a variable defined somewhere else. So in this cases, I would need something to convert it to a string.

Comment: So convert it to a string, what's the problem?

Comment: And next time make a clear statement when writing "*Given the following playbook:*" that you actually expect readers to ignore "the given playbook" and read your mind.

Comment: Well if I used a literal string, it would not provide much benefit over using the inline version. Anyway, converting to a string is not that simple, since it has to be exactly the same string as the inline version. I ended up with `"{{bar| to_json| replace ('\"',\"'\") }}"`. Anyway, thanks for the pointer